# How to do dynamic port forwarding using Ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, ssh, proxy, socks

How do I do SSH dynamic port forwarding on Ruby?

I tried to use gems such as "net/ssh/socks" and "net/ssh/gateway", but it looks like they are already outdated because I can’t even require them.

All I need to do is run this shell command

```
ssh -D 5555 user@host -f -N
```

and receive the PID of this process.

I also tried to use `Kernel#system` and `Kernel#spawn`.

For example:

```
pid = spawn("ssh -D 5555 user@host -f -N")
Process.wait pid
```

This works fine for me, but the PID is always returned 3 units less than the real PID of the process that started. For example, the returned PID is `1555` and the real PID is `1558`.

Another question: why is the difference in the PID always 3 and can there be another difference? Can I use `pid + 3` reliably?

Comment: How do you determine "real PID"? I cannot reproduce this PID issue, as SSH should not be forking when running. What happens if you do `pid = spawn "sleep 300"`? Do you get the correct PID then? Also: how do you check the correct PID, what commands are you running. Best to add this info to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using the SSH binary**

You are running SSH with `-f` (fork). In Ruby, `Kernel.spawn` will automatically fork the process into the background, so you do not need to use `-f`. If you use `-f` you will create a double fork situation, which is the reason for the PID anomaly.

This should be enough to make it work:

```
pid = spawn("ssh -N -D 5555 user@host")
```

**Using Net::SSH with Net::SSH::Socks**

If you want to use `net-ssh-socks` you will have to clone the repository manually, since the Rubygems version has not been updated for the latest Net::SSH.

```
git clone https://github.com/cristianbica/net-ssh-socks
```

Then your Ruby code would look like this, assuming you cloned into the same folder that your script is running in:

```
$:.push('net-ssh-socks/lib')  # Add the cloned repo to load path
require 'net/ssh/socks'

ssh = Net::SSH.start('host', 'user')
ssh.forward.socks(5555)
ssh.loop { true }
```

Comment: Thank you! This solves the issue with PID.So it seems that in Ruby this is the most suitable option for dynamic port forwardnig.

Comment: Seems like it. The `net-ssh-socks` gem is only compatible with `Net::SSH` 2.0.24 (current version 5.x.x). If you are willing to use that version (for example with the help of Bundler), then it will probably work also.

Comment: Daniel see my edit. I added another option that seems to work with the latest Net::SSH release also.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll give you a feedback as soon as I test it.